# How to display full-size images in JQuery Mobile? (Edge to Edge)

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, image-processing

Afternoon, I'm wondering if anyone can help with the following problem.

I have a very simple JQuery Mobile Web-App that I have been playing around with, and this is my CSS. I'm trying to get the 'featured-image' to appear as a full-width image that stretches from edge to edge.

```
featured-image{width: 100%; height: 100px; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0;}
```

I have also tried to put the padding as 0 with !important, but it's not working. My HTML is as followed. If anyone could suggest anything, I would be delighted.

```
 <div class="featured-image">
    <img src="inc/images/keynote-full.jpg">
 </div>
```

Comment: Setting the padding on the image isn't going to do anything if the parent element has padding. Check that first, then you could try negative margins on the image set to the same value as the padding on the parent.

Comment: are you trying e.g. `img{ width: 100%; height 100%; }`?